# How come FileSystemWatcher doesn't fire events, but does with SMSTrace on?

Tags: c#, .net

I create a FileSystemWatcher object to monitor a log file. It's initialized to listen to all possible events (lastwrite, lastaccess, etc..) but it doesn't fire events when the file is being written to.

however, if I open SMSTrace and listen to that file with it (and clearly see that the file is updated constantly) the filesystemwatcher DOES fire events.
What does SMSTrace do to the file?
how can this be explained and how can I fix it?

This is the code:

```
    private FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher;
    private FileStream fileStream;
    private StreamReader streamReader;
    private String fullPath = null;
    private String dir = null;
    private String fileName = null;

    private void selectLogFile()
    {
        // TODO: try to restore previous settings before asking the user for the log file
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fullPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        }
    }


    // TODO: what to do when file erases? (reboot) - clear the window?
    public LogListener()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread selectFileThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(selectLogFile));
            selectFileThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            selectFileThread.Start();
            selectFileThread.Join();

            // The user did not select a file - nothing to do
            if (fullPath == null)
            {  
                return;
            }

            // Create file listener to listen on changes to log
            fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir);

            // Create a file stream to read the data from the log file
            fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            // Create a stream reader from the fileStream to read text easily
            streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

            // Watch for changes in LastWrite 
            fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            // Only watch the log file.
            fileWatcher.Filter = fileName;

            // Add event handlers.
            fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            // Initial syncing of the file
            readFile();

            // Begin watching for events
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Log.Add("Started");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Add("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        readFile();
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        String line;
        String bytesString = "";
        Log.Add(DateTime.Now+":readFile()...");

        // Some more code here...
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some of your code, possibly along with a comparison of how SMSTrace approaches the same type of problem?

Comment: The only thing that's special about SMSTrace is that it *also* uses a FileSystemWatcher.  Used to see changes to SMS log files.  You should never need anything "special" to use FileSystemWatcher on an NTFS volume.  Environmental problems like this tend to have something to do with anti-malware.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, since you haven't provided any code, but...

Did you remember to set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true` on your FileSystemWatcher? e.g.:

```
var w = new FileSystemWatcher("path");
w.Created += DoSomething;
w.Changed += DoSomething;
w.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // No events raised until you do this!
```

EDIT: OK, you're already doing this. Please disregard this answer, I have no idea what's going on :P

Answer (score 0):

Something to look for is your code removing, then re-adding the folder you're watching after you created the flesystemwatcher. If it does that, then the watcher becomes invalid and you don't get any events raised.
I had a bug in my code doing just that today and figured it out after reading this post.